# Indexing a integer in lucene

Tags: lucene

I am using followng code to index a integer value

```
String key = hmap.get("key");
System.out.println("key == "+Integer.parseInt(key));
if(key!=null && key.trim().length()>0)
        doc.add(new IntField("kv", Integer.parseInt(key),IndexFieldTypes.getFieldType(INDEX_STORE_FIELD)));
```

The problem is if 'key' is '50' the line 'key== 50' get printed well but when it reach 'doc.add' line it throw following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: type.numericType() must be INT but got null
at org.apache.lucene.document.IntField.<init>(IntField.java:171)
```

Can someone figure out.

Comment: you're doing `parseInt(minTicketPrice)`  for your debug output, but then are using `parseInt(key)` in the actual `doc.add` call, so you haven't checked at all whether you're passing in an a proper value or not.

Comment: oh sorry its 'key' only in `parseInt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IntField` must have a `NumericFieldType` of `FieldType.NumericType.INT`.  Of course, I don't have intimate knowledge of your `IndexFieldTypes` class, but I would guess it's default `INDEX_STORE_FIELD` has no numeric type (rightly so, if it is non-null lucene will try to index as a number).

You may not necessarily need to pass a field type to `IntField` though, you could just do something like:

```
doc.add(new IntField("kv", Integer.parseInt(key), Field.Store.YES));
```

If you do need to define a FieldType, either use a different type from existing functionality in `IndexFieldTypes`, or implement logic to create an `IntField` from it.  Or just set the NumericFieldType after it is retreived, like:

```
FieldType type = IndexFieldTypes.getFieldType(INDEX_STORE_FIELD);
type.setNumericFieldType(FieldType.NumericType.INT);
doc.add(new IntField("kv", Integer.parseInt(key), type));
```

Comment: `doc.add(new IntField("kv", Integer.parseInt(key), Field.Store.YES));` worked for me.